# Why do i lose some field's values after serializing object into JSON in JScript?

Tags: javascript

I populate object's fields by values in JS and then pass it to the data base with fetch method. I can see, that these fieldes have right values(in console). But when i send this object in JSON to the data base i lose these values. This happens with date and boolean fields. Why is it so?

```
var advToSaveDB = new Object();
var author = new Object();
var rubric = new Object();
$(window).ready(function () {

    var advertisement = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('advertisementToEdit'));

    fillAdvFields(advertisement);

    $("#save").click(function () {


        advToSaveDB.id = advertisement.id;
        advToSaveDB.title = $("#title").val();
        advToSaveDB.text = $("#text").val();
        advToSaveDB.price = $("#price").val();
        rubric.id = $(".select").val();
        author.id = advertisement.authorId;
        advToSaveDB.author = author;
        advToSaveDB.rubric = rubric;
        advToSaveDB.date = advertisement.date;

        var check = document.getElementById('myCheck');
        // var closed = false;

        if (check.checked === true) {
            // closed = true;
            advToSaveDB.closed = true;
        }

        console.log(advToSaveDB.closed);//here is true
        console.log(advToSaveDB.date);//here is right value 

        saveAdv();
        $(location).attr('href', 'http://localhost:9999/MyAdvertisements.html?id=1');

    });
```

and here is my function:
function saveAdv() {

```
 fetch('http://localhost:9999/agency/advertisement/save', {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(advToSaveDB)
    })
        .then(function (res) {
            if (res.success) {
                return res.json();
            }
        })
        .then(function (res) {
        })

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but server is on Java

Comment: Yes but the only code we see is in JavaScript :) When we tag questions the tags have to be relevant to the code we post

Comment: I see. Well, you've not posted any Java so shouldn't have added the tag.

Comment: The issue might be due to your backend platform or ORM. You could have an issue serializing/deserializing or parsing JSON/Date objects. Check that you're receiving the correct JSON in your web service, and then check what kind of data you're attempting to serialize in the database.

Comment: yes, i wrote the date deserialiser and it represents date well. But i see in debugger, that Json is wrong. These fields are not populated

Comment: can you run JSON.stringify and show us the results, clientside, for example after you call saveAdv() function. Date should not be wrong in there

Comment: {"id":15,"title":"'pihywgxw","text":"wdoidjwhndwjdwd","price":"1254","author":{"id":2},"rubric":{"id":"5"},"closed":true,"date":{"year":2018,"month":"JUNE","dayOfMonth":11,"monthValue":6,"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","dayOfYear":162,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"},"era":"CE","leapYear":false}}

Comment: when i do Json.stringify before, it passes param "closed", but date is still null. I suggest, fetch executes earlier